# su to a specific user only if requesting user is in a specific group

Tags: sudo

I need to know how to set up a control user that a user can `sudo` into only if the user is in a certain group. For example, `stupid` is a control user that interacts with a service, and is in the group `stupiduser`. `bill` is a user that is in the group `stupiduser`. `anne` is not in the group `stupiduser`. Only `bill` is able to `sudo` into `stupid`. `ann` cannot interact with `stupid` at all. How can I get a situation like this set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [sudoers man page](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html)

```
User_List ::= User |
              User ',' User_List

User ::= '!'* user name |
         '!'* #uid |
         '!'* %group |
         '!'* %#gid |
         '!'* +netgroup |
         '!'* %:nonunix_group |
         '!'* %:#nonunix_gid |
         '!'* User_Alias
```

simply use (the confusingly named group):

```
%stupiduser HOSTS_HERE = /usr/bin/su - stupid
```

Comment: you might also provide the alternative `%stupiduser ALL = (stupid) ALL` that allows "bill" to do `sudo -u stupid anycommand`.

Comment: Did not work, `visudo` returned text that said that HOSTS_HERE was not defined. I'm going to try @meuh 's method.

Comment: Also, `/usr/bin/su` does not exsist on my filesystem.

Comment: @SpecialBomb You should replace `HOSTS_HERE` by the name of your host, or by `ALL` which means all hosts. Use `command -v su` to find the pathname to your `su` command if it isn't `/usr/bin/su`.

Comment: @meuh I did what you said, but any user can still `sudo -u stupid` without password verification.

Comment: @SpecialBomb You must have another entry such as `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`  that allows all users in group `sudo` to do any command. It is not feasible to disallow someone who can run as root from becoming any user they want to.

Comment: @meuh Oh, well I'm stupid. I should have made a test user. I was using my standard account with sudo group, lol.

Comment: Well, it works now since I used a test user. So, this awnser is officially correct now!